# Google sheet - simple importxml formula does not work

Tags: google-sheets, xml-import

I have tried the below simple importxml formula in a cell

```
=importxml("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_T_postal_codes_of_Canada", "//td")
```

But this always returns a "formula parse error" message.

I don't get it, this example is soo simple. It should work fine.

Comment: Also works for me. Maybe try it on a new sheet, different account or incognito session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make the assumption that you are from Canada. Canada (French) locale uses `;` instead of `,` so most likely it has to do with the spreadsheet locale.

Replace `,` with `;`:

`=importxml("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_T_postal_codes_of_Canada"; "//td")`

Another solution would be to change the locale settings, please read more [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/113082/setting-up-decimal-separator-thousand-separator-and-date-in-google-spreadsheets) on how to do that.

Comment: Had no idea this was a thing!